# Vue @click="item.click || (() => {})" is not evaluating as expected

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm `v-for` some buttons from some data, these data contain `callback` that I want to bind to `<button />`.

I know some of those data have no `callback`, so I wrote this

```html
<button @click="item.click || (() => {})"></button>
```

However, this line is not working as I expected, now, all my buttons' click event is not doing things anymore.

Please see this minimum example

```
<template>
  <div>
    <div v-for="(item, itemIndex) in data" :key="itemIndex">
      <button @click="item.click || (() => {})">Click {{ itemIndex }}</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      data: [
        {
          click: () => {
            alert("First Item");
          },
        },
        {
          // Empty Object
        },
      ],
    };
  },
};
</script>
```

What should I do to prevent empty callbacks?

Here is my [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/vue-clickitemclick-is-not-evaluating-as-expected-e2kcd?file=/src/App.vue)

[image]

(Click 0 is not working)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should do this in the `click` listener:

```
@click="item.click ? item.click() : (() => {})"
```

instead of

```
@click="item.click || (() => {})"
```

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/vue-clickitemclick-is-not-evaluating-as-expected-50ld9?file=/src/App.vue

Comment: Doesn't `item.click()` tries to execute click function instead of just passing function reference to `@click`?

Comment: @JosephWang you are welcome, please mark the answer as the solution if it solved your problem.